# Using Python to make a quiz from a text file

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and I need to make a mini quiz. The questions and answers are in a text file (called textfile.txt), each on its own line. At the end of the quiz, it will tell the user their score out of three.

I can get my quiz to print out the first question, and when I try inputting an answer no matter what I put (correct answer or incorrect answer), it'll tell me it's incorrect.

In the text file I have the following:

```
whats 1+1
2
whats 2+2
4
whats 3+3
6
```

And here is what I have in my .py file:

```
questions = open("textfile.txt", "r")
content = questions.readlines()

userScore = 0

for i in range(1):
   print(content[0])   
   answer = input("What's the answer: ")
   if answer == content[1]:
      print("Correct")
      userScore + 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
  
   print(content[2])
   answer = input("What's the answer: ")
   if answer == content[3]:
      print("Correct")
      userScore + 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
   print(content[4])
  
   answer = input("What's the answer: ")
   if answer == content[5]:
      print("Correct")
      userScore + 1
   else:
      print("Incorrect")
questions.close()

print("You're done the quiz, your score is: ")
print(userScore)
```

How do I make it read the correct answer and keep track of the users score?

Comment: If you really wrote this code yourself, it should not be hard to see where you should initialize the score to 0 and where to increment it for a correct answer. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: @triplee I edited the code and I hope it makes more sense now. I'm stuck because when I enter in the correct answer for question 1 and 2 it tells me the answer was Incorrect.

Comment: @Shub The answer you enter is incorrect because when you read the lines from the textfile it also contains a line-break character at the end of the line (\n). What the program reads as answer for question 1 is 2\n and you are comparing that to 2. Using .strip() on all lines as written below will solve this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `.strip()` to remove the newline characters. The answers comparison might not always work because of them.

To ask every even row you can use the modulo (`%`) operator to get the remainder of the current line index after dividing it by two.

If the answer is correct we add 1 to the `corrent_answer_count` variable that we print in the end.

```
questions = open(r"textfile.txt", "r")
content = [line.strip() for line in questions.readlines()]
questions.close()

corrent_answer_count = 0
for i in range((len(content))):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(content[i])
        answer = input("What's the answer: ")
        if answer == content[i + 1]:
            print("Correct")
            corrent_answer_count += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

print("Correct answer count: " + str(corrent_answer_count))
```